# How to track failure and successful executions from step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-step-functions

I am working on a use-case where I have a Lambda function which invokes parallel step function executions asynchronously based on a MaxJobs parameter feed through events. After all the step function executions are completed successfully the SFN responses should be consolidated and sent as an email to specific users.

Question:
How to store intermittent responses from each SFN executions ?

My Solution:
I think SQS can be leveraged here to store the intermittent responses from all the SFN executions and then once all the executions are completed fire-up the lambda to send email. Not sure whether if it is a right service since the lambda needs to poll these messages and store in S3/DynamoDB frequently as like a cron job.

Another thing, how will SQS know whether all the step function executions have been completed since it needs to trigger consolidated repsonses email in conjunction with SNS ?

Please let me know what will be the best way to tackle this.

Comment: Are these 2 separate SFNs? Do you know which step-functions need to be completed for the email to then be sent?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Only one SFN with multiple executions.

Comment: And you know that for example you’re firing it off 3 times now & when they’re all done, you want the 3 results collated?

Comment: Yes that's correct ! @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Hey @user3928562 ! I am running into this exact same situation. Just wondering how you solved this. I have a step function with multiple executions and I want to pipe the execution logs to an backend store to do some more complex querying

Comment: I stored the intermediate results in S3 bucket @JeremyFisher

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how often you want to do it. An SQS queue would work, yes. If the responses from the Step Function are particularly large, then add a step at the end to store the response in s3 and put the key in the SQS or a Dynamo.

If you know when your original lambda runs how many times the state machine is invoked you can add a metadata fields to a dynamo. Something like:

```
pk: JobBatch# sk: #meta#.  --- attributes: total_started, total_done, job_batch_status: in-progress
pk: JobBatch# sk: State machine execution id
```

then have the last step of the SM update the dynamo with a new entry for its State machine Execution ID - a s3 key if needed or the response if its small enough, some other data you want. And also have it incriment total_done.

Then have a stream to another lambda. That lambda watches the db stream, if its sees total_started == total_done then it fires off the email and updates the #meta# entry to job_complete.

or something.